# Google Apps Script- Increment column each day- Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, increment

I need the apps script to scan each column each day on incremental basis. If it scans one column today say A column, next day the next column B should be scanned.

To trigger the function, daily timer is used for a specific time in a day.
The below code scans all the columns at a time.

The problem here is, the apps script is triggered daily one time. So it starts from beginning. How to store which column it had scanned yesterday and increment it for today.

```
function AutoSend() {  

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var list= new Array();
for(var j= 2; j<=29;j++){  // for Column 
    for(var i=5;i<=23;i++){   // for row
       var value = sheet.getRange(i, j).getValue();
        if(value !== "OFF"){  if(value !== "L") { if(value !== "COMP OFF") {
        var EmpName= sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
        list.push(EmpName);
        }}}
      }
     }
Logger.log(list);
var subject= "sub";
var message = list;          
MailApp.sendEmail('example@gmail.com',subject, message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably need to store data in the document properties.

```
PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty(key, value);
```

You may want to use the date as a string for the `key`, and the column number as the value.

```
var theColumn = 9; //To Do - get the correct column number
var todaysDate = new Date().toString();
Logger.log('todaysDate: ' + todaysDate);

todaysDate = todaysDate.slice(0,15); //Remove time off the end
Logger.log('todaysDate: ' + todaysDate);

PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty(todaysDate, theColumn);

var theColumnForTheDate = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()
  .getProperty(todaysDate);
Logger.log('theColumnForTheDate: ' + theColumnForTheDate);
```

Comment: Thanks Sandy. I will try it out